# If my function is const, do the parameters have to be const as well?

Tags: c++, constants

Say I have a function that should not modify the parameters or anything else in the class, example:

```
bool isPossible(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) const {
    return x1 < x2 && y1 < y2;
}
```

For clarity should I set all the parameters to const as well as the function itself or does it suffice with setting only the function as const (the way I have now)?

That is, should it instead be like this?

```
bool AABB::isPossible(const int& x1, const int& y1, const int& x2, const int& y2) const {
    return *x1 < *x2 && *y1 < *y2;
}
```

Comment: Because the params aren't modified nor should they be as you have this function, you probably should set them to const just from a style standpoint.

Comment: If you choose to provide parameters by reference, const is necessary to guarantee they are not modified. However, note that passing `int`s by const reference is usually equivalent but slower than passing them by value.

Comment: I have edited the question - it seems that OP really had `const` references in mind, not `const int`. I hope existing answers do not suffer from this clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no relation between function being const and parameters of function being const conceptually. They serve different purposes:

- Const function indicates that function should not change class members
- Parameters being const of function mean values of parameters should not change inside function

So if you want your function parameters to be const or not, you should decide separately from the function itself being const.

For example, in your particular case though indeed you could declare your function parameters as `const` since you aren't modifying them inside function (though probably it would not add much in this particular case).

Setting reference parameters as const makes more sense (when it is needed) as addressed in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:  no.

The `const` in your example means that

```
  some_object.isPossible(a,b,c,d);
```

treats `some_object` as `const`, but has no bearing to what the function does to `a`, `b`, `c`, or `d`.

If arguments are being passed by value (like `x1`, etc in your example), declaring them `const` is redundant and unnecessary since, when calling the function, the values provided by the caller are copied - changing them in the function has no effect on the caller.

If an argument is passed by reference or pointer, the `const` matters (with the meaning being that the argument passed is not logically changed by the function) if it is present.   This is independent of the `const` on the function itself though.  So it is possible for arguments to be `const` or non-`const`, independently of whether the function itself is.   There is nothing wrong with

```
  some_object.isPossible(a,b,c,d);
```

being permitted to change `a` and `c` (not specifying `const`) but not being permitted to change `b` and `d` (specifying them `const`).   And these can be handled independently of whether `some_object` can change or not (i.e. if the member function itself is `const`).

Answer (score 1):

The `const` modifier on a function has no bearing on it's parameters. It is only applicable to functions that belong to a `class` or `struct`, in which case it's usually referred to as a method. A `const` method simply means that the method *will not modify the instance of the class it is called upon* but makes no guarantees about it's parameters.

If you want to guarantee that the parameters are not modified, add `const` to the parameters. It's important to understand the difference between passing parameters by value and by reference. In this case, each parameter is given by value, so anyone calling this function already knows that the original variables given to this function cannot be modified by the function. The only benefit of using `const` is that you can't accidentally assign to your parameters. The situation is different for parameters passed by reference, where the presence of `const` is necessary if you want to guarantee that the original variables given to the function are no changed.

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned `const` member functions and `const` function parameters are two different concepts.

The following code illustrates the differences:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    void PrintState() const;
    void UpdateState(const int newA, const int newB);
private:
    int a;
    int b;
};

MyClass::MyClass()
    : a(10), b(20)
{}

void MyClass::PrintState() const
{
    /*
     * Note: the following is not possible due to the member function being const. 
     * a = 30;
     */
    std::cout << "A: " << a << ", B: " << b << std::endl;
}

void MyClass::UpdateState(const int newA, const int newB)
{
    /* 
     * Note: the following is not possible due to the parameters being const.
     * However, updating the data members is fine.
     * newA = 30;
     * newB = 40;
     */
    a = newA;
    b = newB;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters take into account that these two declarations declare the same one function

```
bool isPossible(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) const;
bool isPossible(const int x1, const int y1, const int x2, const int y2) const;
```

The both functions do not change the original arguments passed to the functions. Function parameters are its local variables.

Thus the using of the const qualifiers influences only on the body of the function.

The corresponding first definition of the function can be imagined the following way

```
bool isPossible(/* int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2 */ ) const
{
    int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2;
    //...
}
```

The second definition when the qualifiers are used can be imagined the following way

```
bool isPossible(/*const int x1, const int y1, const int x2, const int y2*/) const
{
    const int x1, const int y1, const int x2, const int y2;
    //...
}
```

For the caller of the functions it is entirely unimportant how the local variables are declared within the functions. It would be important if the corresponding arguments were accepted by the functions by reference. However for the functions above arguments are passed by values that is the functions deal with copies of arguments. Thus whether to use the qualifiers or not is not very important. It has only self-documented meaning for function body implementations.

Let's assume the the function calls some other function and passes the first own parameter by reference to the other function.

```
bool isPossible(/*const int x1, const int y1, const int x2, const int y2*/) const
{
    const int x1, const int y1, const int x2, const int y2;
    //...
    call otherFunction( &x1 );
    //...
}
```

In this case if you expect that the original value of x1 would be the same during all the function execution and that other called functions would not change the value of x1 by mistake it is better to declare the parameter with the qualifier const.

Consider the following example

```
#include <iostream>

void g(int *x) { *x += 10; }
void g( const int *x ) { }

struct A
{
    void f(int x) const
    {
        int prev_x = x;

        g( &x );

        if (x != prev_x)
        {
        std::cout << "x = " << x << ". Oops, x was changed!" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "x = " << x << ". x was not changed" << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    A().f(10);
}
```

The function output will be

```
x = 20. Oops, x was changed!
```

The problem is that by mistake the programmer forgot to cast the pointer to a const pointer like this

```
g(const_cast<const int *>( &x ));
```

To avoid such a mistake it makes sense to declare the parameter with the qualifier const

```
void f( const int x) const
{
    //..
```

to select the correct overloaded function for the call

```
g( &x );
```

Answer (score 0):

const function you mean const this pointer which means that that member function won't change or modify the class members not the parameters.

the parameters passed in by value shouldn't be modified so it's recommended to use them as const. this is useful where the body of the function is big and uses them so to avoid modifying them by accident pass them as constants. in your case it's ok to pass them as const or modifiable as long as there's no big code.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not required that you make the parameters be `const` as well. The way you are passing your arguments is by value so your parameters well be merely copies of the original.

The benefit of `const` parameters comes from passing pointers or values by reference in C / C++.

Comment: okay so i should instead do `bool AABB::isPossible(const int& x1, const int& y1, const int& x2, const int& y2) const{
    return *x1 < *x2 && *y1 < *y2;
}` ?

Comment: As @giorgimoniava said, a `const` parameter and `const` function has two separate and unconnected purposes. For this example there is no need for `const` parameters, or to be passing them by reference as you're only doing a comparison.

Comment: @Bonbin I think your comment is a part of your question, and it shows what you really wanted to ask. I have edited your question accordingly.

Comment: also, you do not have to de-reference parameters passed in by `int&`

Comment: I understand that, but i read somewhere else that i should use references where ever possible and also to use const for clarification purposes. This is also a requirment from my teacher